# Function $\phi (x,y) \mapsto \phi (u,v)$ [ie:...] under the transformation $f(z) = u(x,y) + v(x,y)$ where $f(z)$ is analytic & $d_z \,f(z)$ is not $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, chain-rule

I am just having a bit of trouble understanding what I am being asked.

The ie: in title says $\phi [x(u,v), y(u,v)]$

Part a) is asking to do the laplacian, $\nabla^2_{x,y} \phi (x,y)$ and to write it in terms of $\nabla^2_{u,v} \phi (u,v)$ and $d_z \, f(z)$. Part b) is showing that if one is harmonic the other is harmonic too, seem simple once I get going.

I know that this is just applying the chain rule to $\nabla^2_{x,y} \phi (x,y)$ with $u$ and $v$ plugged in but I don't quite understand how $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ enters the picture.

What I got so far is  $\nabla^2_{x,y} \phi (x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 \phi[(x(u,v),y(u,v)]}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi[(x(u,v),y(u,v)]}{\partial y^2}$ but I am not sure what to do from here or if this is the right interpretation since, again, I don't see how $f(z)$ comes in.

Comment: You can do part a) in terms of just $u$ and $v$, but I think when you get to the end they will want a simplification of the result based on $f$ being analytic, i.e., on $u$ and $v$ satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Suggestion:  chug away with the chain rule, then try to simplify with Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Sound advice. After looking at it even more, I think that I am suppose to apply the Laplacian to  $\phi (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ rather than $\phi (x(u,v),y(u,v))$ as in the given 'ie:...'. Anyways, thank you for the input.

Comment: For the record I solved the problem... it was far more trivial than expected. If anyone stumbles into this question, the above two comments are exactly what you have to do. Someone is free to write up a solution for archive' sake. Also, thanks Micheal for the clean up edit.